# Иное действие во время закрытия модалки bootstrap при условии

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

есть стандартная модалка bootstrap, есть кнопка next которая должна закрывать модалку, но при закрытии модалки нужно производить определённые действия (очищать внутреннюю форму), а при нажатии кнопки next, форма не должна очищаться.
Может как то вешать дата атрибут на кнопку и проверять его во время ивента `hide.bs.modal`? 
Всё что придумал - проверил, сюда решил обратиться, т.к уже крайний случай.
Спасибо

Добавить кнопку для отчистки формы не вариант, от этого решения и пытаюсь уйти.

---

Проблему решил навесив дата при нажатии на кнопку next:

```
$('#next-button').on('click', function () {
   $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

И при евенте закрытия модалки проверял дата:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   if ( $('#next-button').data('clicked') ) {
        console.log('not clean');
   } else {
        console.log('clean');
   }
});
```

Comment: Bootstrap какой версии? Есть какой то минималистичный отрывок кода который может помочь понять, то что вам требуется? При закрытии модального окна очистить форму, при кнопке next закрыть окно но форму не очищать?

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```js
// $('#exampleModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
//   $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
// });

$('#next').on('click', function(){
  
  $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
  alert('next');
});

$('#close, #exampleModal .close').on('click', function(){
  
  $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
  $('#exampleModal').find('form')[0].reset();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="close" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
        <button id="next" type="button" class="btn btn-success">NEXT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```